# Lint Error on 'check permission'

Tags: android, android-permissions

When i ran lint on my project i am getting several security exception related to

```
  Cursor managedCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            URI, null, null, null, null);
```

and

```
   startActivity(callIntent);
```

as showing

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential
>   `SecurityException`

for location i am able to solve this by putting checkselfPermission by like this,

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                                    || mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            }
                        } else {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        }
```

What are the necessary condition(permission) required for **Cursor** and **startActivity**.

SDK Version: 23

BuildTool Version : 23.0.1

Comment: Have a look here http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I know to suppress lint warnings. I have added it in build.

Comment: because `getLastKnownLocation` requires permission